# Microsoft Translator custom model deploy failed

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I've tried two times to deploy an already successfully trained model in Microsoft Custom Translator dashboard (Bleu score: 38.31).

The deploy process ends always with "Deployment Failed" status, not any error message. The model is the first and the only one present in the project.

I have a S1 subscription plan. Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Thanks
Max

Comment: please contact support at custommt@microsoft.com with details of your model.